# Sparrow Toolkit Chart Line Series Tracker

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I've created a simple line-series chart using [Sparrow toolkit](https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/), but i do not find a way to create "trackers" onto my data points.
This would allow to display something like a tooltip of a selected point/nearest point on the line series that contains some more information about that point (or at least the x/y values).

My code is basically that from the [online data demo](http://sparrowtoolkit.apphb.com/).

```
<sparrowToolkit:SparrowChart Foreground="Black" 
                             FontFamily="Arial" 
                             Margin="5">
            <sparrowToolkit:LineSeries Label="Series" 
                                       PointsSource="{Binding Data}" 
                                       XPath="X" 
                                       YPath="Y" />
</sparrowToolkit:SparrowChart>
```

With Data Binding from the ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Data
{
    get { return mData; }
    set { mData = value; }
}
```

and a custom Model for the data points with **X**, **Y** and **Description** properties.

*Is there even a way to add those tooltips to the datapoint in Sparrow? Would be nice to have also the Description property in that "Tooltip".*

Thx for any help!